# Vaadin - adding text on top of an image

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am building a custom layout with Vaadin and I have Images that act as buttons (with a clicklistener). However I also need to display some text and I would like to display it over the image, so inside the image really. Is this possible and if yes, how?

```
Image dayCourt = new Image(null, new FileResource(new File(basepath + "/VAADIN/images/9_Available_18_Available.png")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I also need to display some text and I would like to display it over the image, so inside the image really. Is this possible and if yes, how?

The most straight forward way to do this is to wrap Image and Label (with the text you want to place over the image) inside CssLayout. Then you need to add style name to the label. In your theme you need to set z-index for the Label (so that it floats on top of image) (see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp ) and position absolute to Label (see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) relative to corner of the CssLayout

Also, if your Image happens to be static content, i.e. you do not have need to change the image on the fly, you could have even simpler solution. Instead of thinking composite of two components inside CssLayout, you could have only the Label and set the image from theme resources to be the background of the Label (see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).